# How does C−Br bond obtain energy through solvation?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

I came across a question related to S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanism. In an example of S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction, i.e. hydrolysis of *tert*-butyl bromide to form *tert*-butyl alcohol, the following was given in NCERT *Chemistry: Textbook for class XII, Part II* [[1, p. 304](http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?lech2=1-7)]:

> Step I is the slowest and reversible. It involves the C—Br bond breaking for which the energy is obtained through solvation of halide ion with the proton of protic solvent. Since the rate of reaction depends upon the slowest step, the rate of reaction depends only on the concentration of alkyl halide and not on the concentration of hydroxide ion.
>
> Further, greater the stability of carbocation, greater will be its ease of formation from alkyl halide and faster will be the rate of reaction. In case of alkyl halides, 3° alkyl halides undergo S<sub>N</sub>1 reaction very fast because of the high stability of 3° carbocations. We can sum up the order of reactivity of alkyl halides towards S<sub>N</sub>1 and S<sub>N</sub>2 reactions as follows:
>
> $$
> \def\CL{{\large\text{Tertiary halide; Secondary halide; Primary halide;}~\ce{CH3X}}}
> \ce{->[\text{For}~\mathrm{S_N2}~\text{reaction}][\CL]} \\
> \ce{<-[\hphantom{[\CL}][\text{For}~\mathrm{S_N1}~\text{reaction}]}
> $$

How does C-Br bond obtain energy through Solvation of bromide ion ?

#### References

1. NCERT. *Chemistry: Textbook for Class XII. Part II*, Reprint: August 2019 Bhadrapada 1941; M. Siraj Anwar, Shveta Uppal, Arun Chitkara, Bibash Kumar Das, R.N. Bhardwaj, Mukesh Gaur, Series Eds.; National Council of Educational Research and Training: New Delhi, **2007**. ISBN 978-81-7450-716-7. ([PDF](http://ncert.nic.in/textbook/textbook.htm?lech2=1-7))

Comment: @andselisk Thanks for completing reference. I mentioned it because you have mention ACS style so I thought that we need to mention abstract of ACS research paper

Comment: No prob. You can find a brief summary with examples regarding using ACS citation style [here](https://libguides.williams.edu/citing/acs) or in the [PDF from the corresponding chapter in the earlier edition of ACS Style Guide textbook](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/bk-2006-STYG.ch014). A CSL style file for your reference manager can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/american-chemical-society.csl).

Comment: These release of energy is due to the neutralization between the oppositely charged halide ions and protons which get attached during solvation and hence they get stabilized by releasing energy.

Comment: I think the terminology is a little bit misleading in the book. They probably meant to say that the carbocation and bromide ion pair is stabilized by solvation by water. This means that the C-Br bond can break in a rate limiting step. Imagine that there was no water, the reaction was in vacuum, then you would never get a stable ion pair, because the electrostatic attraction would always push them towards each other.

Comment: @ShoubhikRMaiti. Yeah It sounds reasonable.